# getting driving distance using google maps direction API

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I've used both XML and JSON to get driving distance by google maps direction API, (I use ASP.NET, C#), but both methods have problems in giving correct values, they give some 0 values and sometimes they don't give any value at all. What is the best way for getting driving distance between two points? can you give me a working sample

It is my XML method:

```
 string strURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" + Session["UserLat"].ToString() + "," + Session["UserLon"].ToString() + "&destination=" + tmpList[d].X + "," + tmpList[d].Y + "&mode=driving&sensor=false";
List<float> distances = new List<float>();
distances.Clear();
HttpWebRequest wRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
//Request.Headers.Add("Man", "GET " + strURL);
HttpWebResponse wResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wRequest.GetResponse();
if (wRequest.HaveResponse)
{
    if (wResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        StreamHandler = new System.IO.StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream());
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(StreamHandler.ReadToEnd());
        Response.Write(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance").Count.ToString() + ",");
        for (int w = 0; w < xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance").Count; w++)
        {
                                                            distances.Add(float.Parse(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance")[w].ChildNodes[0].InnerText));

        }
    }
}
```

some of my distances are 0, what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code you have that is not working correctly?

Comment: Can you please post the values of origin and destination where you get a distance of 0 ? Maybe there wasn't returned a direction(e.g. you can't drive from tokio to berlin)

Comment: no, this is not my problem, both locations are in a city, I can easily view returned XML when I type the request in my browser, but ASP.NET sometimes returns 0 directions!

Comment: Well I am not sure why you are getting `0`. I would guess it is something else you are doing later on with the information, as this code looks correct (could use some cleanup though, like you should only call `xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName` once to get the `XmlNodeList` as opposed to doing that before the loop and twice every loop iteration.